# Alternatives to set screen resolution on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have 2x 4k60fps monitors connected to my machine using a single DP cable that goes through a splitter (like daisy chain) to connect to both.

I am aware that 2x4k60fps is too much resolution to pass through a single DP cable, but it does support the same resolution at 30fps, because I can get it to work on Linux and Chrome OS.

On Windows 10, as soon as I select "Mirror screens" the dialog tells me that it cannot apply the configuration (because it defaults to 4k60fps), and it doesn't give me the chance to "finish" building my config. As a result, I cannot use both monitors at the same time.

Is there a way to set this configuration on Windows 10? Either through the stock configuration tool or another program?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to try to enable 4k @ 30hz, Try: Settings > System > Display > Advanced display settings > Choose display > Refresh Rate (select 30 Hz) [or Display adapter properties for Display (#) > List All Modes to see if 4k @ 30Hz is listed.  If it is not, you will need to update the driver for your display adapter to one that has that resolution, if available].  If you can get your main display to 4k @ 30Hz, you should be able to enable the second one with the same refresh.

Comment: I can enable 30Hz on monitors individually, but I still get the same error when I change to "Extend desktop" :(

Comment: What is the brand/model of your display adapter?  I would suggest seeing if you can find an updated driver directly form your manufacturer to see if it works better.

Comment: My sistem is a NUC8i7HNK, and I have installed the drivers and software for the GPU (Radeon RX Vega M GL). Unfortunately it can only tweak color settings and some presets, but links to Windows' tool to arrange monitors.

Comment: Perhaps try starting with lower resolutions (1080p) first and see if you can get the extended desktop to work that way, then raise the resolutions of each screen one at a time?